# How to build Programm from Source at Fedora 13?

Tags: fedora, c++, build

I just installed Fedora 13 on my Notebook. Because I am a long time Windows user, I now face a big problem. I downloaded the Source for a specific cbr-reader but I dont know, how to build it. 
I know how to compile some c++ code, but unfortunately that´s it. 
The Programm is called [Comical](http://comical.sourceforge.net/) and requires besides the gcc 3.3 the wxWidgets. I downloaded the Source and wxWidgets already, but I really don´t have any clue at all what to do now.

Please can someone give me some advise or HowTo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `wxGTK-devel`, `gcc-c++`, and `make` packages, then run `make` in the extracted directory followed by `sudo -c 'make install'`.

Or install the `comix` package and use that.

Comment: I tried to run make but, the code is kind of old, so i always get an error about some bools in the code. So I tried the comix package and it works perfectly. At least I know now how to build something. Thanks again.